# Need clear idea about timespec structure

Tags: c, linux, time, gettime

In my project I'm using `struct timespec` as follows

```
struct timespec start, end;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&start);
/* Do something */
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&end);
```

It returns a value as `((((unsigned64)start.tv_sec) * ((unsigned64)(1000000000L))) + ((unsigned64)(start.tv_nsec))))`

Can anyone tell why we are using the `unsigned64` format and also help me understand this structure in detail?? I'm using this code in my study about time calculation in nanoseconds precision for the code execution time taken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unsigned 32-bit type (like `unsigned int` on modern platforms) have a max value of a little over four billion. If you have 5 and multiply that with one billion (like done in the code in the question) you will get a value of five billion, larger than can be contained in a 32-bit unsigned type. Enter 64-bit types, which can hold a ***lot*** higher values (`18446744073709551615` to be more precise, to compare with an unsigned 32-bit max value of only `4294967295`).

---

By the way, the code can be simplified like

```
start.tv_sec * 1000000000ULL + start.tv_nsec
```

This simplification is possible because the compiler will automatically convert lower-precision types and values to higher-precision as needed. As you have an `unsigned long long` (that's what the `ULL` means) literal value in the expression, the rest of the expression will also be converted to `unsigned long long` and the result will be of type `unsigned long long`.

Comment: once if I don't use (unsigned64) I'm getting error message and the build is not successful. And I use " %lld " Is that ok?

Comment: Some build error bro.. I didn't notice what was it.. Was trying it the whole day yesterday and got vexed..